# Toggling working in the controller but not in the Spec: Rails 3 + Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, tdd, rspec, rspec2

Given this confirm method:

```
  if (@bucket.confirmation_code == @code)
      puts "OLAAA"
      @bucket.toggle!(:confirmation)
      @bucket.save
      flash[:success] = "Successfully confirmed bucket."
      redirect_to bucket_url(@bucket)
    else
      flash[:fail] = "Error confirming bucket."
      redirect_to bucket_url(@bucket)
    end
```

I have a spec testing if it toggles the confirmation attribute but even though in the controller, everything seems to be working (`confirmation == true`), the test is failing (`confirmation == false` instead of `true`).

The test is as:

```
it "should have a confirmation URL" do
        @attr3 = {:email => "test@testing.com", :confirmation_code => "ola123"}
        post :create, :bucket => @attr3
        @bucket = Bucket.last
        post :confirm, :id => @bucket.id, :code => "ola123"
        @bucket.save 
        @bucket.confirmation.should == true
      end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `@bucket.save`, which is unnecessary since your controller method will already do this, do `@bucket.reload`, which will re-query the database for the current values (which changed since you first assigned `@bucket = Bucket.last`). Then your `confirmation` value should return `true`.